# How to generate cache CustomKey for Redis in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis

I have spring boot application which is integrated with Redis cache. Have to implement caching for one of the method call. That method argument is an object with multiple params which is external Request object. This object params will vary for each request also based on that param and its values output of the method is varies. I need to create a cache key using that Request object field/param values. How to achieve it.

We can use **SimpleKeyGenerator** only when method params are static?

```
UserService.java

@Cacheable(value = "usercache", keyGenerator="customKeyGenerator")
public UserResponse getUserResp(User user){

//Some backend calls
return user

}

User.java

public class User {

private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private Integer age;
private Date dob;
private Address address;

// Another 10 params

}
```

In this method implementation User object is dynamic. I have to create a cache key based on User object fields which is having valid non null values. How to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented as like below.

```
User.java

public class User implements Serializable {

private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private Integer age;
private Date dob;
private Address address;

// Another 10 params

@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        //Add necessary fields
    }

@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
   //Add necessary fields
}
}


public class UserKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator{
    
    private static final String UNDERSCORE_DELIMITER = "_";

    @Override
    public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {
        
        String cacheKey = null;
        if(params.length > 0) {
            StringJoiner paramStrJoiner = new StringJoiner(UNDERSCORE_DELIMITER);
            User userReq = (User) params[0];
            
            paramStrJoiner.add(target.getClass().getSimpleName());
            paramStrJoiner.add(method.getName());
            paramStrJoiner.add(String.valueOf(userReq.hashCode()));
            cacheKey = paramStrJoiner.toString();
        }
        
        return cacheKey;
    }
```